# Does using `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` violate the one-definition-rule?

Tags: c++, datetime, c-preprocessor, one-definition-rule

When using `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` in a header file, the results of the preprocessor for that header inclusion can be somewhat different.

Under which circumstances does using `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` in a header file violate the one-definition-rule?

As a follow-up: Does the `assert` header violate the one-definition-rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `__TIME__` gives different results for different translation units, then it must not be used in a context where the same result is required across translation units. This means e.g. initialising an object (e.g. a class member) to `__TIME__`, where that initialiser is part of a header that gets included in multiple translation units, is going to be problematic.

`__DATE__` is less likely to give different results for different translation units if you start a fresh build, but incremental builds, ones that only recompile the files that changed, do make it likely to become a problem as well.

`assert` is a macro that expands differently depending on how `NDEBUG` was defined when its header was included, so either the whole project must agree on whether `NDEBUG` should be defined, or functions defined in headers should avoid using `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

The one definition rule is only applicable to variables, functions, class types, enumerations, or templates (e.g. Section 3.2, ISO/IEC 14882, 1998 C++ Standard). `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` are both predefined macros that expand to a string literal - which is not one of the things that the one-definition rule is applicable to.

`assert()` is also a preprocessor macro.  If its expansion defines a variable, function, class type, enumeration, or template, then its use could potentially violate the one-definition rule, if that definition differed between translation units.   Pragmatically, it is difficult to envisage a situation in which an implementation would have an `assert()` macro that expanded to such a definition.